# Does Mongodb automatically updates indexed items?

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I created an index using:

> db.collections.createIndex({'key': 1})

then will all new documents added to the collection with field 'key' automatically added in the index?
Or do I need to run reIndex() after certain number of new documents?

Comment: Of course it updates every time something is written. This is how indexes work. Also answered in the documentation: ["How to Write Operations Affect Indexes"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/indexes/#how-do-write-operations-affect-indexes)

Comment: See also [Why and when is necessary to rebuild indexes in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30366749/2313887)